# Best way to use multiple sorting drop-downs with one output table?

Tags: php, html-table

I am using PHP to output the result of a MySQL query. I have the query set to display all rows, to restrict based on 1 value, or to restrict on more than 1 value.

However, I'm wondering how best to make the PHP to control the selection of the values to restrict the query.

The TH tags of the output table will have dropdowns, which will reload the page and use $_GET to pass the query values.

So far I have made one dropdown selection as so:

```
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="nikki.php" <?php if (!isset($status)) { echo "selected"; } ?>>状況選択</option>
<option value="nikki.php?status=finished" <?php if ($status == "finished") { echo "selected"; } ?>>完了</option>
<option value="nikki.php?status=waitingforcallback" <?php if ($status == "waitingforcallback") { echo "selected"; } ?>>電話待ち</option>
<option value="nikki.php?status=unfinished" <?php if ($status == "unfinished") { echo "selected"; } ?>>末完了</option>
</select>​
```

As you can see, the selection calls the page with a status tag to pass the data to the query.

However, what if I wanted to make another (or more) dropdown selections?

```
<select onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '&type=AAA'?>">A</option>
<option value="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '&type=BBB'?>">B</option>
<option value="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '&type=CCC'?>">C</option>
</select>​
```

I know I could do things like check the URL, then append either `"?status=XXX"` or `"&status=XXX"` depending on the current URL status, but that would involve lots of ifs and doesn't seem like the best way to do what I want to accomplish.

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: What about an onchange to call a js function. In js you look at all of the selected values to build the new query string?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a loop through an array of type?

```
<?php $types = ['AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC']; 
      foreach ($types as $type) { 
        $linkValue = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '&type='. $type; ?>
        <option value="<?= $linkValue ?>"><?= $type ?></option>
   <? } ?>
```